# How to adjust form values sent to iframe without showing changes to a user?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm sending form data to an iframe (`<form target="myIframe" ... >`) because I need to upload a file and because I don't want to reload the page.

The problem is that I need to encrypt some data of the form. Surely I can replace values in form with encrypted values but it would not be really user-friendly. Is there some kind of callback to adjust the data of submitted form in javascript/jQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use SSL.

```
<form action="https://..."
```

You need to load the page that displays the form via SSL to, otherwise it can be interfered with by a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: I would use https but I don't have money for a certificate.

Comment: Then use a self-signed certificate.

Comment: From what I have read about self-signed certificate it just creates a false feeling of safety. I'm considering buying a certificate in future but for now I would rather encrypted it myself.

Comment: By using a self-signed cert you lose having a third party verify your identity (and that the cert belongs to you) … which you also lose with any homebrew system.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that in more detail!